# How can I squelch Node JS's console logs for requests?

Tags: node.js

I don't want to see a log for every request the server receives when I'm testing (it makes reading the results much harder). Is there a simple way to start up Node so that it doesn't do that?

I'm referring the the lines that look like this just to be perfectly clear:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [Mon, 07 Jan 2013 15:59:52 GMT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1039 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Chrome/10.0.613.0 Safari/534.15 Zombie.js/1.4.1"
```

Comment: Which framework are you using? AFAIK raw node doesn't log requests

Answer (score 3):

NodeJS does not do this automatically.

Assuming you are using `express`, you need to remove the `logger` middleware. Remove this line:

```
app.use(express.logger());
```